# Installing programs without apt-get

Tags: apt, proxy, emacs

I would like to install some programs on a computer which uses a proxy
to access to the Internet.
I tried to configure the proxy access but for reason that I do not
understand this does not work.
I can surf the web but not use `apt-get`.
I get some errors containing `401 unauthorised` which I do not
understand bu make me think that the proxy is meant to prevent the
type of connection that `apt-get` uses.

I mainly want to install emacs. how can this be done simply using a
web browser?

Comment: `apt` uses HTTP, so it's strange that you had trouble. You might want to try again, by either running `export http_proxy=local.proxy.domain:800` - obviously using the correct server and port - or by adding `Acquire::http::proxy "http://local.proxy.domain:800/";` to /etc/apt/apt.conf

Comment: I am not sure about the port. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always download the `.deb` packages and install them manually using

```
dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

To download the package, go to [this web page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=emacs) and select your Ubuntu version.

You will find a web site giving you alternate package versions (emacs23-lucid and emacs23-nox, the latter only to use with a terminal); also, you will find a number of dependencies -- packages that you must install before installing emacs, for example [common emacs binaries](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/emacs23-bin-common). `dpkg` will complain about unsatisfied dependencies.

That said, I would rather search for a solution with your proxy setup, because you will have a recurring problem with updates (including security updates) and installing new software. Ask a new question with details on the error messages and your proxy configuration.

Comment: nice answer :) You're right to say that about fixing the proxy though; often installing a .deb which isn't from the ubuntu repos will prevent that package from getting updates or will cause it to do strange things to dependencies...

Answer (score 3):

This might seem not proper way but it works take a terminal and run 
sudo apt-get install emacs

Since proxy is not working you will get error messages , see at the end of error messages you can see like this

Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/emacsen-common/emacsen-common_2.0.3_all.deb  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/emacs23-non-dfsg/emacs23-common-non-dfsg_23.4+1-1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
......

This are the files that are need too install emacs, if you are patient enough copy paste each link and download the files into a folder.

then copy the entire files to /var/cache/apt/archives then again run

sudo apt-get install emacs, it should work.

And please note this might not work if you havnt never run a successful sudo apt-get update